# Upgrade to 23.04 complete, but system still reports as 22.04

Tags: upgrade

I've just run the update programme to upgrade to 23.04 from 22.04.3. The update appears to have completed successfully. No errors were returned from the update programme, repositories now appear to be pointing at 23.04 and all packages have been updated correctly.

But strangely the system is still reporting itself as being on 23.04.3. GNOME Settings > About and neofetch both report the system as being 23.04.3. More importantly, the Software Updater programme still displays the message "Ubuntu 23.04 is now available (you have 22.04)", with a link to upgrade. Clicking the "Upgrade" button does nothing; no updater is launched.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it? Odds on it just fixing itself once 23.10 is released and the new updater turns up?

Edit: To add detail, the reason why the update triggered now in particular is that until now the machine had been set to update to LTS versions only, and I changed this setting to "every release". I expected the behaviour to be to upgrade in hops to 22.10 and on to 23.04, but I didn't think too hard about the fact that it offered an upgrade directly to 23.10.

The output to `cat /etc/os-release && sudo apt update` is below.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease         
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease          
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease       
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done                       
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

So you can see what I mean- version is reporting as 22.04.3, but the repositories have clearly been updated to point at Lunar. Packages have updated themselves accordingly, for example `gnome-shell` is at 44.3-0ubuntu1.1.

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns no output.

Comment: What is reported by `lsb_release -a`?  And I would think that from 22.04.3, you should first go up to 22.10...and then to 23.04.  I wasn't aware you can go directly to 23.04...

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?  *Many apps will read results from memory; and the new release on disk won't be recognized until apps restart, where a reboot is the easy workaround*

Comment: The system has been rebooted several times, and lsb_release reports the same: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: I couldn't possibly comment on the upgrade path directly from 22.04.3 to 23.04; I just ran the update from Software Updates as usual and let it do its thing. The updater application that ran was called "lunar", and the repos have been updated to target 23.04, so that's definitely what it was trying to do. Whether it was meant to is a different matter!

Comment: There is a different app that is run to perform a [*release-upgrade*](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) instead of normal upgrades will will not change a *jammy* (22.04) release (upgrading only 22.04.2 to 22.04.3 for example). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LunarUpgrades has details on *LunarUpgrades*.  The `base-files` package for *jammy* is `base-files | 12ubuntu4.4    | jammy-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` where 23.04 will have `12.3ubuntu2`, If you `apt-cache policy base-files` you can see what you have

Comment: I'd run `sudo apt update` and read what's there. Details you've provided imply you're using 22.04 or *jammy*, if you are using *jammy* or 22.04 your `gnome-shell` version will be `42.9-0ubuntu2` (use `apt-cache policy gnome-shell` to view) where as *lunar* or 23.04 will use `44.3-0ubuntu1.1`.

Comment: Offers to release-upgrade should have begun appearing in January 2023, and ceased in May 2023. Are you saying that the system didn't offer any release-upgrades before now?

Comment: What does running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do or output if any?

Answer (score 2):

Typing all that out and talking with a user on another forum, I see the error! It's that pesky `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease` repo. Updating that to lunar in `/etc/apt/sources.list` has solved it; the system is now correctly reporting itself as 23.04, and the phantom release upgrade is no longer being offered.

Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced same issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04. Although the upgrade process went smoothly and the UI updated to 23.04, the system still reported it was on version 22.04 when I checked the 'About' section or ran lsb_release -a.

Initially, I checked my /etc/apt/sources.list file to ensure the repositories were correctly set to 'lunar', which they were. However, the issue persisted.

**Here's how I resolved it:**

1. I ensured all packages were up to date using:
   sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
2. I then tried manually installing the base-files package which contains the version information:
   sudo apt-get install base-files

Finally, I rebooted my system:

Upon reboot, running lsb_release -a now correctly displays Ubuntu 23.04. If anyone faces a similar issue, I hope these steps can help.